# Recorrer un array multidimensional en PHP y traer valores

Tags: php, array, web, foreach

Tengo el siguiente objeto y quiero traer solo los id__ de la posición 0 y 1. Intenté con un foreach pero solo puedo traer el valor de cada id por separado. Hay alguna forma de traer y guardar el valor de ambos id__?

```
array(2) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#14 (3) { ["USER_CODE"]=> string(10) "magonzalez" ["name"]=> string(5) "Motos" ["id__"]=> int(1) } [1]=> object(stdClass)#15 (3) { ["USER_CODE"]=> string(10) "magonzalez" ["name"]=> string(5) "Hogar" ["id__"]=> int(2) } }
```

Por ejemplo si hago lo siguiente "var_dump($response->{'value'}[0]->id__);die;" Solamente me muestra el valor del id__ de la posicion 0. Yo quiero que me muestre los valores de ambos id__ de la posicion [0] y [1]

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con "traer"? Es muy ambiguo ese concepto.

Comment: Perdón. Me refiero a mostrar o guardar el valor de ambos id__

Por ejemplo si hago lo siguiente "var_dump($response->{'value'}[0]->id__);die;"   Solamente me muestra el valor del id__ de la posicion 0. Yo quiero que me muestre los valores de ambos id__ de la posicion [0] y [1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

Por lo que veo tu tienes un arreglo de objetos y no un arreglo multidimensional

No mencionas la versión de PHP que estas utilizando así que mi respuesta tendrá que ser un poco genérica

A partir de PHP7 en adelante puedes utilizar una función en php que se llama array_column, puedes encontrar la documentación [aquí](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-column.php)

Esta función se usa específicamente para obtener los datos de la columna que deseas

Podrías hacer algo así:

```
$resultados = array_column($tuArreglo, 'id__');
```

Eso te regresará un arreglo con los valores de "id__", no importa cuantos índices tengas en tu arreglo va a devolver todos los "id__"

Si usas una versión anterior de PHP entonces no puedes usar array_column, tendrías que usar array_map porque antes de PHP 7 array_column no soporta arreglos multidimensionales ni arreglos de objetos

Comment: GRACIAS! Me sirvió mucho. Te lo agradezco